# Controlling Firefox from C++

Tags: c++, windows, interprocess

I am running Mozilla Firefox on Windows 7 and would like to be able to send simple commands (New Tab, Minimize, Close Tab) to it from a C++ program.

The usual question of inter-process communication, when both processes are a part of the same user program, seems to be answered by [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

But what about actually controlling the GUI window of an entirely independent application (Mozilla)?

Comment: This is oh so much easier with IE, actually.

Comment: @chris, I would guess so, being an integrated part of the OS. However, I do not plan on switching away form Mozilla. As a matter of fact, an OS-agnostic solution would be the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spy++ to debug what messages each action will produce, then replicate those [messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your program.

Comment: Things like new tab are very free not to send messages like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ranorex http://www.ranorex.com, Quick Test Pro http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-testing-automation/index.html#.UpvC8OJO7tw

Will give you this ability

Comment: It looks like I would need to purchase the product. Being a hobby projects, I am not willing to spend money on it.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to controlling any Windows program through its user interface is by sending it Windows messages. There are also some rather specific Windows APIs that allow you to send specific kinds of inputs directly to the keyboard, mouse or other input device.

Assuming simple requirements, you should be able to control Firefox by sending it some combination of the messages WM_[SYS]KEY[DOWN|UP], WM_[L|R]BUTTON[DOWN|UP] or similar. You may also need to use FindWindow and other things to find where to send messages. And liberal use of Spy++ to figure out what to send and where to.

Actually, what I would do is start with AutoHotKey. It can do all this stuff and then some, and it has a massive community. It's GPL so you can find out how it does stuff and there are people there to ask for help.

Comment: Actually, the general answer is to use UI Automation.

Comment: It might be, if this was a C# question. I don't think the OP was intending to write managed C++.

Comment: There are (confusingly) two things both called UI Automation. There is a core OS feature called UI Automation, which is COM-based (therefore callable from C++). There is also a C# wrapper around UI Automation, also called UI Automation.